# Take a screenshot and display it as a smaller image on the bottom of the screen

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have implemented a screenshot feature but I am not sure how to display this taken image on the screen of my device. I could use Image/RawImage component but how do I reference it since I am destroying the texture after encoding.

```
   public Image img; //Reference the screenshot image here

   void Capture()
   {
     StartCoroutine ("TakeScreenshot");
   }
    WaitForEndOfFrame frameEnd = new WaitForEndOfFrame ();

    IEnumerator TakeScreenshot() {

        // Create a texture the size of the screen, RGB24 format
        int width = Screen.width;
        int height = Screen.height;
        yield return frameEnd;
        var tex = new Texture2D (width, height, TextureFormat.RGB24, false);

        // Read screen contents into the texture
        tex.ReadPixels (new Rect (0, 0, width, height), 0, 0);
        tex.Apply ();

        byte[] bytes = tex.EncodeToPNG ();
        Destroy (tex);
        var form = new WWWForm ();
        form.AddField ("plant", plantComponentID);
        form.AddBinaryData ("image", bytes, "screenShot.png", "image/png");
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't destroy it. Only destroy it when replacing it e.g.

```
public Image img; //Reference the screenshot image here

void Capture()
{
    StartCoroutine ("TakeScreenshot");
}

WaitForEndOfFrame frameEnd = new WaitForEndOfFrame ();

IEnumerator TakeScreenshot() 
{
    // Create a texture the size of the screen, RGB24 format
    int width = Screen.width;
    int height = Screen.height;
    yield return frameEnd;
    var tex = new Texture2D (width, height, TextureFormat.RGB24, false);

    // Read screen contents into the texture
    tex.ReadPixels (new Rect (0, 0, width, height), 0, 0);
    tex.Apply ();

    byte[] bytes = tex.EncodeToPNG ();

    // Do not destroy the texture
    // Destroy (tex);

    // If the image already has a previous texture destroy that one
    if(img.sprite)
    {
        if(img.sprite.texture) 
        {
            Destroy(img.sprite.texture);
        }

        Destroy(img.sprite);
    }
    // create a sprite from the new texture
    var sprite = Sprite.Create(tex, new Rect(0,0,tex.width, tex.height), Vector2.one * 0.5f);
    // and assign it
    img.sprite = sprite;

    var form = new WWWForm ();
    form.AddField ("plant", plantComponentID);
    form.AddBinaryData ("image", bytes, "screenShot.png", "image/png");

    ...
 }
```